# how to pass textarea value to javascript function on button click

Tags: button, textarea, titanium, appcelerator

I would like make that when user inputs any data on textarea, my Calculate button makes any calculation. At this point, how can I hold the data which is given by user in order to send it to Calculator button? Anyone know how it can be?

Here is the textarea, user gives any data

```
var textAreaHeight = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#bbb',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#888',
    font: {fontSize:20, 
    fontWeight:'bold'},
    keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_GO,
    left:200,
    top: 300,
    width: 125, 
    height : 40
});
```

Here is my button which makes any assumpitons

```
var CalculatorButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Calculate',
    top:475,
    width:400,
    height:90,
    left:75
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
  var CalculatorButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title:'Calculate',
        top:475,
        width:400,
        height:90,
        left:75
        });


      CalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var result=textAreaHeight.value
        alert(result);
        });
```

Thanks